# Composite functions and proofs

Tags: functions

I'm looking for proofs to show for example:

$g \circ f$ is one to one if $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one.
Or perhaps if $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, are $f$ and $g$ one-to-one?

Basically are there proofs regarding the commutativity of composite functions based the properties of one-to-one, onto and invertible? It seems that composite functions are not commutative but I can't seem to find a justification for this claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition is one-to-one iff f is one-to-one and g is one-to-one on the image of f.